# Error instantiating servlet class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer

Tags: rest, servlets, jersey

Hi Trying to write a simple rest webservice. And following the tutorial below:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/index.htm

But i am getting
HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer

Exception:

```
<body>
        <h1>HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <p>
            <b>type</b> Exception report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>message</b>
            <u>Error instantiating servlet class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>description</b>
            <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>exception</b>
        </p>
        <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
</pre>
        <p>
            <b>root cause</b>
        </p>
        <pre>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
```

Following is the code (Which is mostly same as the tutorial)

```
package com.abhi;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/UserService")
public class UserService {

   UserDao userDao = new UserDao();

   @GET
   @Path("/users")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   public List<User> getUsers(){
      return userDao.getAllUsers();
   }    
}
```

My Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>MyRestPrjct</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.abhi</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Typically that's due to either including Jersey 1.x jars or not having those jars in the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was just not placing the jars in proper way. Instead of placing the required jar in `webapps\MyRestPrjct\WEB-INF\lib`, I was placing it in `webapps\MyRestPrjct\WEB-INF\lib\libs`.

It is working fine after I the moved the jars from `libs` to `lib`.

Answer (score 4):

Placing all the jars in WEB-INF/lib folder resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

i too faced similar issue when i did the same tutorial, the problem i found out was the servelt class specified in the web.xml is

```
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
```

but when i checked in the jars there is no package in the libraries with the above path so i change it to the existing one

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
```

and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same exception when trying to run the same module from tutorialspoint. All I did is to download the below jars and added to project. It worked fine.
`jersey-common-2.0-m03.jar`
`jersey-server-2.0-m03.jar`
`jersey-container-servlet-core-2.28.jar`

Answer (score 0):

In my case worked by adding maven dependencies in deployment assembly.(For Maven Project*)

```
Right click project name (in eclipse) > configure build path > Deployment Assembly (in Left bar) > Add > java build Path Entries > Maven Dependencies > Finish
```